# Converting preview data to Bitmap?

Tags: android, android-camera, yuv

In following method,

```
public void onPreviewFrame4(byte[] data, Camera camera)
```

data is come in Yuv Format, is there any way for converting it to RGB, because i have tried it using following method

```
  static public void decodeYUV420SP(int[] rgba, byte[] yuv420sp, int width,
    int height) {
final int frameSize = width * height;

for (int j = 0, yp = 0; j < height; j++) {
    int uvp = frameSize + (j >> 1) * width, u = 0, v = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < width; i++, yp++) {
        int y = (0xff & ((int) yuv420sp[yp])) - 16;
        if (y < 0)
            y = 0;
        if ((i & 1) == 0) {
            v = (0xff & yuv420sp[uvp++]) - 128;
            u = (0xff & yuv420sp[uvp++]) - 128;
        }

        int y1192 = 1192 * y;
        int r = (y1192 + 1634 * v);
        int g = (y1192 - 833 * v - 400 * u);
        int b = (y1192 + 2066 * u);

        if (r < 0)
            r = 0;
        else if (r > 262143)
            r = 262143;
        if (g < 0)
            g = 0;
        else if (g > 262143)
            g = 262143;
        if (b < 0)
            b = 0;
        else if (b > 262143)
            b = 262143;

        // rgb[yp] = 0xff000000 | ((r << 6) & 0xff0000) | ((g >> 2) &
        // 0xff00) | ((b >> 10) & 0xff);
        // rgba, divide 2^10 ( >> 10)
        rgba[yp] = ((r << 14) & 0xff000000) | ((g << 6) & 0xff0000)
                | ((b >> 2) | 0xff00);
    }
}
```

}

but it will not work properly for me.

Please provide any other way to convert it to Bitmap.

Thanks...!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set following property of camera to get preview in RGB image format than no need for conversion.

**[Camera.Parameters.setPreviewFormat(ImageFormat.RGB_565);](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#setPreviewFormat%28int%29)